# Instantiate XMLConfiguration from spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to instantiate [XMLConfiguration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/XMLConfiguration.html) from spring appcontext, my configuration file is in

```
src/main/resources/
```

But when I try to pass the constructor args like this :

```
<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="classpath:/config.xml"/>
```

or

```
<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="classpath:config.xml"/>
```

The spring cannot locate the file :

> org.apache.commons.configuration.ConfigurationException: Cannot locate configuration source classpath:/config.xml

But I can see it inside the war, in

```
\WEB-INF\classes
```

Can anyone think what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`classpath:/config.xml` is Spring-style, and Commons Config doesn't know what that means.  You need to pass a path to `XMLConfiguration` that it knows how to interpret.  The javadoc link that you posted suggests that `XMLConfiguration` requires an actual file path, not a classpath reference.

Comment: I've tried `${webappRoot}/WEB-INF/classes/config.xml, /WEB-INF/classes/config.xml , src/main/resources/config.xml` sam error always, how would you put location of that configuration if you needed to do the same, or maybe there is another way of injecting property file location?

Comment: @London: Personally, I wouldn't use Commons Configuration at all. There's no point when using Spring.

Comment: thank you for your response, what would you use? I'm using configuration file not for spring, but for table creating in a view, so I can manipulate the with them from javascript.(+1)

Comment: I'll accept your answer thank you for your effort and time spent to answer this, I found work arround here http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=229044, `You can also have your setter/constructor take a java.io.File. Spring knows how to convert from a file system or classpath reference into a File. You should be able to use the level of abstraction which suits your situation.`